# datastax opscenter - how is 'storage capacity' determined?

Tags: cassandra

I installed the OS version this recently (5.0.2) and am wondering about this graph. To date I've had a hard time finding a metric for 'cluster capacity' when it comes to Cassandra. Magically, datastax seems to have an answer. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a writeup of the capacity service. Essentially it keeps track of things like data growth over time, transactions per second growth, etc. It then tries to come up with a trend:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/online_help/services/capacityService.html

Sadly this is more of a "for management" metric though and usually does not mean anything. It just takes one new app/script/etc added into the environment to make all the trends invalid. At least that has been my experience.

Comment: Interesting. It's hard to see how measure like these would give a value for 'capacity' in Gb. I can imagine something more akin to 'projected usage'.